# Why is my file not Downloading (HTMLUnit) Java

Tags: java, api, download, htmlunit

I am on this website and I am trying to fill out the fields and press submit:
http://www.hmdb.ca/spectra/ms/search

After clicking submit, I am trying to download the results as a CSV (there is a button).

My attempted solution is (s, r, t, z are string inputs):

```
public static String hmdb() throws IOException {
      WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
      Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
      webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
      HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.hmdb.ca/spectra/ms/search");

      HtmlTextArea searchBox = page.getElementByName("query_masses");
      searchBox.setText(s);

      HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementByName("ms_search_ion_mode");
      HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByValue(r);
      select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);   

      HtmlInput searchBox2 = page.getElementByName("tolerance");
      searchBox2.setValueAttribute(t);

      HtmlSelect select2 = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("tolerance_units");
      HtmlOption option2 = select2.getOptionByValue(z);
      select2.setSelectedAttribute(option2, true);

      HtmlSubmitInput Button = page.getFirstByXPath("//input[@value='Search'][@name='commit']"); 
      HtmlPage pageafter=Button.click();

      HtmlSubmitInput Button2 = pageafter.getFirstByXPath("//input[@value='Download Results As CSV'][@name='commit']"); 
      Button2.click();
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. No file is being downloaded. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are almost there:

```
UnexpectedPage page3 = Button2.click();

// then copy from page3.getInputStream() to the preferred location

IOUtils.copy(page3.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream("c:\\output.csv"));
```